# Problems finding a cell with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to find the value of a cell in excel, by first locating the row that it's in and then passing through the coordinates of the cell (the column will be the same each time).

I tried using the code below, the problem with it is that it rownum is not the number of the row (as I was expecting). Please can someone help me to find the number of the row that contains the value I'm looking for:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\rtemp\\Names.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet5']
rownum = 0

for row in ws:
 for cell in row:
    if cell.value == 'ResellBalance':
        rownum = row
        break

ExcelValue = ws.cell(row=rownum, column=2).value
print(ExcelValue)
```

Comment: Why do you think that `for row in ws:` will iterate through the rows of the worksheet? Have you read the [tutorial](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.3/tutorial.html)? It specifically mentions how to iterate through the rows of a sheet

Comment: I've read through the tutorial and searched google for answers. I'm aware that for row in ws returns the whole row. I'm trying to find a function that returns the row number, so far all I can find is a function that returns the column (get_column_letter)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a function that locates the row number, but I can find the row number with the cell value I'm looking for by using the following:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\rtemp\\Names.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet5']
rownum = 0

for row in ws:
 for cell in row:
    if cell.value == 'ResellBalance':
        rownum = rownum + 1
        break

FieldName = (ws.cell(row=rownum, column=2).value)
```